# In Backbone.js, after I 'create' a model under a collection, how do I update that model?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

```
Posts.create({'body':post_body});
```

When I call that, Backbone will hit my sever with an AJAX post request, creating that post.  My server will then return a JSON with the "full" post.

Perfect! But now, I want the newly created model to to have the full data. In other words, I don't want it to only have the body attribute. (all my other models have other data).

My question is:

- will backbone automatically update the model with the "full" data because my server returned that full JSON?
- if not, how can I get Backbone to update that model so its data is full?

**Edit:**  I did this, and it seems like Backbone automatically uses the data returned as the new model. Can someone confirm?

```
success:function(post){
    console.log(post.toJSON()); //Yay! latest version.
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the model will be updated with any additional info your server returns.

This is because under the model's `create` method, there is a call to `save`, which intern calls `model.set` within it, in order to update the model with any amended (or new attributes).

As the [source code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-41) comment for this method states:

> If the server returns an attributes hash that differs, the model's state will be set again.